# Trying to place a file in a remote destination

Tags: batch-file, copy

I'm attempting to replace an old executable on a system that's currently running the program with a new copy of said program.  I've been able to make some headway but it seems I've twisted myself up a bit and am now getting errors.  Here's what I'm trying to do:

1) Prompt technician for the IP address (this works)
2) Kill the program actively running on the target system (this works)
3) Copy the new executable from the "current directory" to the appropriate place on the target system. (Sideways)

I've attempted many iterations of this but I cannot seem to find a combination that works using either copy or xcopy (attempted the same code using both).

```
set /p ROOT="Enter Machine IP Address: "
taskkill /S %ROOT% /IM mobileRecorder.exe /F
taskkill /S %ROOT% /IM mobileMenu.exe /F
set TARGET=\\%ROOT%\C$\Program Files\MobileRecorder\
xcopy mobileRecorder.exe %TARGET%
```

The above yields "Invalid number of parameters" error (using COPY it reads, "The syntax of the command is incorrect")

I have also attempted to combine the last two lines using:

```
xcopy mobileRecorder.exe \\%ROOT%\C$\Program Files\MobileRecorder\
```

And:

```
xcopy .\mobileRecorder.exe \\%ROOT%\C$\Program Files\MobileRecorder\
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xcopy mobileRecorder.exe "%TARGET%"
```

Since `target` contains a space, you need to group the string to provide a single token.